# How to change class element from Dom component in GrapesJS

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

I've been looking for an answer for a bit now, and would like to find an answer. So here is the question : I need to update a class name of a GrapesDom element that have been added using editor.DomComponents.addType('myComponent'). (Below the full code I am using)

```
  editor.DomComponents.addType('myComponent', {
    isComponent: function (el) {
      if (el.getAttribute && el.getAttribute('data-gjs-type') === 'myComponent') {
        return {
          type: 'myComponent'
        }
      }
    },
    model: containerModel.extend({
      defaults: {
        ...containerModel.prototype.defaults,
        tagName: 'div',
        classes: ['container'],
        traits: [
          {
            type: 'select',
            name: 'default',
            options: [
              { value: 'value_1', name: 'value 1' },
              { value: 'value_2', name: 'value 2' },
              { value: 'value_3', name: 'value 3' }
            ],
            label: 'Défault'
          }
        ],
        editable: false,
        stylable: false,
        hoverable: false,
        propagate: ['editable', 'stylable', 'hoverable', 'selectable'],
        components: {
          type: 'row',
          classes: ['row'],
          selectable: false,
          propagate: ['editable', 'stylable', 'hoverable', 'selectable'],
          components: {
            type: 'column',
            classes: ['col'],
            components: myCustomComponent
          }
        }
      },
      init () {
        this.on('change:attributes', this.handleChange);
      },
      handleChange () {
        console.log('value ', this.getAttributes()) // This is working

        // Here I would like to add a class name to an existing class of the component. Depending on the attribute, I'd like to change the position of 'active' class.

      }
    })
  })
```

Here is the HTML myCustomComponent part

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-1 active"> test 1 </div>
  <div class="nav-2"> test 2 </div>
</nav>
```

Anybody would have an idea of how to do this ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if it's a little late but the only missing thing is to use `addClass` method to add your `active` class. [Here](https://codepen.io/jvas28/pen/rNOrWXK?editors=1111) you can see a working example

```
...
 handleChange (attr) {
     doSomething(attr);
     if(something()) {
       this.addClass('active')
     }

 }
...
```

#### note

I see you are using `isComponent` checking if attribute `data-gjs-type` is the name of your type. You don't need that, because if that attribute is already setup the method `isComponent` won't run and the type will be assigned directly.